# Why a reference to const can refer to a literal?

Tags: c++, reference

Why a "plain" reference can't refer to a literal, and a reference to const can do? As far as I know a literal is not an object!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to change the value of `42`.

That doesn't mean that the language *technically* couldn't support lvalue references to literals. After all Fortran did that, as I recall. It just has to create a temporary automatically and pass a reference to that.

But then you can easily get into trouble with code like this:

```
void advance( int& x ) { ++x; }

void foo()
{
    unsigned i = 7;
    // ...
    advance( i );     // Would advance an automatic temporary's value.
    // Here there would be no change to `i`.
}
```

---

Regarding

> **”** a literal is not an object!

The literal `42`, of simple `int` type, doesn't denote an object. There's not necessarily a data memory location that holds that value. You can't take its address like <del>`&42`</del>.

However, as just one example, the literal `"Blah"` denotes an object: you can take its address, like `&"Blah"`.

Comment: Oh, well. So it is nothing too necessary or complex, thanks :)

Comment: Back in the early days, FORTRAN didn't create a temporary. You could modify the literal itself, with obviously disastrous results.